# PHP: Looping data with JSON response

Tags: php, json, loops

I'm trying to get my data from database and I can get it but there is an error I'm getting two copies of those records. I don't understand why my looping is not working. You can find the code below. I didn't initiate a php code so it would not be a SQL injection. Please Guide.

```
if( mysqli_num_rows( $result ) > 0 ) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $flag[checkdate]=$row[checkdate];
        $flag[checkno]=$row[checkno];    
        $flag[datepaid]=$row[datepaid];
        $flag[clientname]=$row[clientname];
        $flag[bank]=$row[bank];
        $flag[amount]=$row[amount];
        $flag[status]=$row[status];
        array_push($info, $flag);
    }
        $response["success"] = true;
        $response["message"] = $info;
        echo json_encode($response);
}
else
{
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No entries yet";
        echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What is happening? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: What is `0s` -> `mysqli_num_rows( $result ) > 0s`?

Comment: sorry i didn't see that i will re edit

Comment: i want get only 1 data but its still looping

Comment: If you are getting 2 result rows, then you need to look at your query to see how many rows it is returning. There is nothing here that would cause duplicate rows. So either your query is returning 2 rows, or this code is inside a loop.